# How would EF handle computed property?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

Given the following class

```
public class Model
{
    public int ActualInt{get;set;}
    public int ComputedInt {get {return ActualInt * 2;}}
}
```

How would EF *not* map the ComputedInt.

I also would prefer not suly my domain model with `NotMappedAttribute`

Fluent is also a pain because I have to keep removing the mapping per context, per computed property and there are a lof of those in the domain model.

Is there a way to do this, simply by convention instead of configuring explicitly?

Comment: @Tyriar  Yes and no the model is shared with RavenDb, I am somewhat tired of all the attributes and productivity loss they incur. On the RavenDb site for example there's a bunch of "JsonIgnore", but wait RavenDb has its own version of NewtonSoft, so if I want to serialize the DomainModel via regular NewtonSoft and choose to ignore certain properties, there's now another "JsonIgnore" identical, but referencing different assembly. Long story short, the attributes are just going crazy.

Comment: Properties with only a getter and no setter are by convention not included in the EF model. So in this case `ComputedInt` shouldn't be mapped.